# Change values inside an xml file at runtime

Tags: android, xml, sharedpreferences, android-settings, user-preferences

I have an activity where a user can change the apps color accent.
The choosen color is saved inside `SharedPreferences`.

Instead of having a static value inside the apps `colors.xml` file I would like to be able to change that by whatever is saved in the apps `SharedPreferences`.

```
<color name="colorAccent">#value_from_shared_preferences</color>
```

I know there are other different ways to use a user specified color as the apps accent color, but I would like to know how to switch out the value inside the apps `colors.xml` file.

**Update:** All resource values are constant so it's not possible to change values inside xml file at runtime.

**Ref:** [Programmatically change the value of a color resource obtained from API response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33987678/programmatically-change-the-value-of-a-color-resource-obtained-from-api-response/33992017#33992017)

Comment: You can't change the value once your project has been compiled. http://stackoverflow.com/a/33992017/1269953