# Changing the color of the background of an Activity

Tags: android

I am trying to change the color of the background in my android app. At the moment when I press the button it changes the color for that specific activity and not for all the other activities. Is there a way to change it for the whole app?

[image: screen]

```
public class colorPicker extends AppCompatActivity {

    View view;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_color_picker);

        view = this.getWindow().getDecorView();

    }

    public void goPink(View v){

        view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.Pink);
    }

    public void goGreen(View v){

        view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.Green);
    }

    public void goYellow(View v){
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.Yellow);

    }
}
```

Comment: save the bg color in preference and get your bg color on load from preferences

Answer (score 0):

You could change the window background color of your **app theme** and don't use a background for activities or you can use a transparent background for activities.

Answer (score 0):

create a theme in your styles.xml and add following to that theme

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/window_background
```

and set `android:theme="@style/YourTheme"` in your

```
<application>
...
</application
```

in manifest file

Comment: I believe this is a solution if I want to choose a specific color as a developer. I want the user to choose a color by pressing a button in the activity and then according to that, the color will change. I hope I am making it clear!

Comment: Go through this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33987678/programmatically-change-the-value-of-a-color-resource-obtained-from-api-response

Answer (score 0):

In this case, You need to add few changes in your activity.
  In on onCreate

```
 if(getIntent().getExtras() != null)
    {
        int theme = getIntent().getIntExtra("theme", R.style.AppTheme);
        setTheme(theme);
        getApplication().setTheme(theme);
        //recreate();
    }
```

Condition onCLick

```
  if(condition)
   getIntent().putExtra("theme", R.style.AppTheme2);
   else
   getIntent().putExtra("theme", R.style.AppTheme);
```

and maintain 2 theme

```
 <style name="BaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
  <item name="colorPrimary"></item></style>
```

and the second theme similar to it just change the name as BaseTheme2.

But this is not suggested to change the app theme at runtime.

Comment: There is no `Intent` in the question. The color comes from the button click event.