# Create service to detect any action from the user

Tags: java, android, service, android-service, sensors

I'm trying to create a service where I want to detect something about user, let's say when user lays the device on a table, the thing is that I have that action detected but I have it on a `MainActivty` and I want it to put on `Service`.
The thing is that on my `MainActivity()` I had my `registerAction()` and on my `onResume()` were called and in `onPause()` I call the `unregisterListener()` from my `sensor`, as well I have a `HandlerThread` where I start it on my `onCreate()` how do I change it to `Service`? Would be a problem? I see that there aren't the same methods...

I've created my `Service` and I've got :

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    public MyService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d("CREATE","ONCREATE");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("DESTROY","ONDESTROY");
    }
}
```

Also my `MainActivity` I have put `implements SensorEventListener`.

A skeleton of my class is :

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

    private HandlerThread mSensorThread;
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mSensorThread = new HandlerThread("sensor_thread");
        mSensorThread.start();
    }

    private void registerSensorListener() {
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST, new Handler(mSensorThread.getLooper()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        //DO stuff
        if (isLayed()) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                   Log.d("LAY","LAYLAY");
                }
            });
            mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }

    private boolean isLayed() {


        return stuff;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        registerSensorListener();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }
}
```

### EDIT

I'm using szamani20 code, but I'm having problems with `runOnUiThread` because I can not call from my `Service` also, I'm having this issue

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.example.developer.qwe.MyService@d8c613b with null: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getAction()' on a null object reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to decide whether you want the user to be aware of your running service or not. Take a review on [Background Execution Limits in android Oreo](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html):

> To improve the user experience, Android 8.0 (API level 26) imposes limitations on what apps can do while running in the background.

So considering your case where it seems there are lots of work to do in many situations, it would be a better approach to use a foreground service. As [android document says about foreground services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground):

> A foreground service is a service that the user is actively aware of and is not a candidate for the system to kill when low on memory. A foreground service must provide a notification for the status bar, which is placed under the Ongoing heading. This means that the notification cannot be dismissed unless the service is either stopped or removed from the foreground.

Since you mentioned that you have the action detected I won't enter that part of your code. So you need to create a subclass of `Service` as you did and use the `startService` method to get it's `onCreate` called. One thing you need to notice is that the `onCreate` method of service is called once you call `startService` on that service for the first time, no matter how many times you call `startService` again the `onCreate` method won't get called and only the `onStartCommand` get called. We use that fact alongside that you could provide a string action within your `intent` to properly register and unregister your listener.

In `MainActivity.java`:

```
String action = "start";  // Or to unregister listener "stop"!
final Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
intent.setAction(action);
startService(intent);
```

and then in `MyService.java`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // Do initialization or whatever here (executed once per service lifecycle)
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals("start")) {
        // Register your listener or whatever
        showForegroundNotification();
    }
    if (intent.getAction().equals("stop")) {
        // Unregister your listener or whatever
        stopForeground(true);
        stopSelf();
    }

    return START_STICKY;
}

private void showForegroundNotification() {
    Intent myServiceNotificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    myServiceNotificationIntent.setFlags(
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent
            .getActivity(this, MY_SERVICE_REQUEST_CODE,
                    myServiceNotificationIntent, MY_SERVICE_FLAG);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle(MY_SERVICE_NOTIFICATION_CONTENT_TITLE)
            .setTicker(MY_SERVICE_NOTIFICATION_TICKER)
            .setContentText(MY_SERVICE_NOTIFICATION_CONTENT_TEXT)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_whatever)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .build();
    startForeground(MY_SERVICE_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
}
```

Finally don't forget to unregister your listener in `onDestroy` in case of android kill your service (which is very rare):

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // Unregister your listener
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try it

Comment: But where should I put the code to detect the event?

Comment: I provided a comment in `onStartCommand` and `onCreate` and I explained about that. You may want to initialize your data in `onCreate` and register and unregister your listener in `onStartCommand`.

Comment: I'm having troubles with runOnUiThread inside of service... it's not called

Comment: @Stuart2041 please provide more information, what error exactly are you getting on which line?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.example.developer.qwe.MyService@d8c613b with null: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getAction()' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

You can register SensorManager inside service in OnStartCommand.Also try using startForeground as android os will kill your service when app is killed