# Programmatically change the value of a color resource in colors.xml

Tags: android, colors, android-theme

I tried this [Programmatically change the value of a color resource obtained from API response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33987678/programmatically-change-the-value-of-a-color-resource-obtained-from-api-response/33992017#33992017) it is working.But we need to set the color for every element with setBackgroundColor() based on id of that element.is there any way to change in colors.xml file

Comment: can you please more explain what you want ?

Comment: can you please post the code?

Comment: Do you want to change the values of colors  which resides in colors.xml file?

Comment: Basically, based on configuration on sever properties, I need to change the skin of my android application completely.I got few solutions like with reference of id of element i can change the color.  This should be done for every activity/Fragments. Is there any other way to  update the colors.

Comment: You can't alter resource files programmatically.

Comment: can't we update values files