# Adding String or Color resources programmatically

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-resources

When my application is started `MainActivity` is opened.In `MainActivity` I have a Api call as `getApplicationLabels` which returns me a `JSONObject`.I have suppose 5 `Fragments` in app.The Fragment contains some views as `TextView`,`Edittext` having hints etc.The attributes like text,size,color etc of these views need to be set programmatically from String,Color resources. This values I will receive from that getApplicationLabels Api call after Login and will be different for different user. How to add this received values from api into Strings.xml, colors.xml etc and set the labels for all views in app.

Comment: have u check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33987678/programmatically-change-the-value-of-a-color-resource-obtained-from-api-response/33992017#33992017

Comment: Create your custom views extending `TextView`, `EditText` etc. make a method there and update views @ runtime.

Comment: You **can't add anything** to the `res` folder **at runtime**.

Comment: Perhaps use SQLite and store it in a db instead?