# How to programmaticaly change color of a color resource?

Tags: java, android

I want to change a button that has a shape with a color set:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/custom"/>
    <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

and in my colors list resources I have `<color name="custom">#A281E0</color>`.
Is it possible to programmatically change the color of custom? Thanks in advance

Comment: You can change the color of a view "on the fly", but you cannot write to a resource file.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will be better to use dynamically color changing, like this:

```
String color = "your hex color"
Int colorToUse = Color.parseColor(color)
```

Then set a background color of your button:

```
Int buttonId = findViewById(R.id.button_id)
buttonId.setBackgroundColor(colorToUse)
```

Set a color that you need to `color` variable. Something like this.

Comment: Then you can handle it what you need, like `onClick()` or in `onCreate()` methods etc.

Comment: I agree with this option, but my intention was to automatically change color for dozens of buttons by changing one color they all target

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment because i don't have enough reputation.

Why do you need to do this? Perhaps there is another plan of attack to solve the requirement, for instance a state list drawable, which will allow for different drawables based on varying state - ie selected, focused, etc.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#StateList

Answer (score -1):

Because I'm a newbie I can't mark this a duplicate but I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33987678/programmatically-change-the-value-of-a-color-resource-obtained-from-api-response) will give you the answer you want. Apparently, you can create a class that extends Resources and override the method getColor(int).