# How can I change app colors programmatically?

Tags: android, resources, android-resources

I want change to my primary colors at runtime. I can change it with custom themes and colors. But I want to change my color from service result not static styles code. Is there any way to change colors.xml programmatically.

I find a solution but that's deprecated now: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34178187/6155031

Comment: `Is there any way to change colors.xml programatically` you can't change any xml file, as far as i know, and the colors.xml file won't be any different

Answer (score 0):

- Create one Singleton class that defines all the colors that you want
  to change in your app.
- Set its properties on app load from JSON file
  obtained from the cloud.
- In your app, wherever you are using color codes, don't set those values in xml. Set color values in your Java/Kotlin code.
- I assume you are aware of findViewbyId. :-)