# Dymamic color resources on runtime

Tags: android, android-layout

We are building an app that decides the color of the app based on the login. When someone logs in for a specific company we get the color codes from the API. Is it possible to use them as color resource?

Answer (score 1):

You can't change `colors` at runtime, but there are some workarounds to do dynamic colors. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33987678/programmatically-change-the-value-of-a-color-resource-obtained-from-api-response)

Keep in mind that: If you do that, you & your designers will have ton of things to do to have contrast colors (colors `on` the background), color above another color,... This mean "You have to do theming for each color from api"

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting color hex code as string you can do the following.

```
String colorCodeFromApi="#2222FF";    
int color = Color.parseColor(colorCodeFromApi);
```

you can put this color in some constant file and can use it when ever required.

If you are using data binding concept then you can create a binding adapter inside that you can set the color of the view.